# Array Manipulation with Sql query from php to display it on HTML?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-server, multidimensional-array

I am trying to display a table on html page queried from PHP. These three arrays will always have same length:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{   
    $SUBJECT[] = "$row[SUBJECT]";
    $SECTION[] = "$row[SECTION]";
    $SCORE[] = "$row[SCORE]";
}  
// I know this part is confusing. I will elaborate why i am doing this later
$count = [];
$total = [];
$perc = [];

for($i = 0, $length = count($SUBJECT); $i < $length; $i++) 
{
    if(!isset($count[$SECTION[$i]][$SUBJECT[$i]]))
    {
        $count[$SECTION[$i]][$SUBJECT[$i]] = 0;
        $total[$SECTION[$i]][$SUBJECT[$i]] = 0;
    }
    $count[$SECTION[$i]][$SUBJECT[$i]]++;
    $total[$SECTION[$i]][$SUBJECT[$i]] += $SCORE[$i];
    $perc[$SECTION[$i]][$SUBJECT[$i]] = round($total[$SECTION[$i]][$SUBJECT[$i]]/$count[$SECTION[$i]][$SUBJECT[$i]],2);
}

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>";
echo "<tr><td></td><td>" . implode("</td><td>", array_unique($SUBJECT)) . "</td></tr>";
foreach(array_unique($SECTION) as $v)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$v</td>";
    foreach(array_unique($SUBJECT) as $key)
        echo "<td>" . (isset($perc[$v][$key]) ? $perc[$v][$key] : "0") . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This would output a table like this on my html table something like this(the value in this table are already averages):

```
                Math    Science     English     History     PE
Section A       90          50          40          60      100
Section B       60          50          70          70      90  
Section C       60          50          70          20      80
```

This is what i need help with:
I want to create an overall row under the section that would display the average of all of the subjects. So that would look like:

```
Overall  70    50    60    50   90
```

I know i would start like this after the `foreach(array_unique($SECTION) as $v)`:

```
}
echo "<tr><td>Overall</td>";
echo "<td>".   ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>;
```

Now i am thinking i would need to rearrange the arrays from the start differently:

```
$SUBJECT[] = ('MATH', 'SCIENCE', 'HISTORY', 'MATH', 'PE'.....)
$SECTION[] = ('A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A'...)
$SCORE[] = (50, 80, 70, 80, 60 ...)
```

So the point of that little block of code is to create this table where there is subject and section and tells the average score (essentially sql has each student, so i am averaging there scores so i can display data by each section and each subject).

So how to create an overall row for subject and sections?

**UPDATE:**
I just realized i made this harder than it needs to be:

I guess my question is i have two array:

```
$SUBJECT[] = ('MATH', 'SCIENCE', 'HISTORY', 'SCIENCE', 'PE', 'MATH', 'PE', 'PE');
$SCORE[] = (50, 100, 70, 60, 90, 70, 80, 100);
```

I want a to create a new array that show gives me average of this:
So i call: `$newarray['MATH'] = 60; $newarray['SCIENCE'] = 80; $newarray['PE'] = 90; etc.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this one http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

```
    $newarray = array_combine($SUBJECT, $SCORE);
```

Comment: I looked at that. I could not work with it since cant have the same key in an array. It would only show the recent value.